# Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of isjson function

Tags: json, sql-server

I have existing db table, i cannot change its structure as it is live and is running some critical systems.  I have an ntext field which has a blob of json i want to query on that json using sql server.  When i try to query i get the error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 63
>   Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of json_query function.

So after some digging it seems that json operations are not supported on ntext fields.  So is there something I can do to get round this without having to change my table structure?

Comment: Did you try to convert to `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: You could `CAST` as `nvarchar(MAX)`. Better to change the schema to `nvarchar(MAX)` given `ntext` has been deprecated for nearly 15 years.

Comment: Just one of many reasons why not to use something that was replaced 15 years ago by something better. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as per suggestions casting to nvarchar(max) did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Here's the syntax for casting the ntext field to NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
SELECT CAST(NtextField AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```